# In my server saying "Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web..." but I have mysql in my application

Tags: mysql, .net-assembly

```
    Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

...

    Line 240:      <providers>
    Line 241: <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, 

.....
```

Resolved to putting the tag in the web.config file  the following line:

```
<remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider"/>
```

I do not have access to the server settings to remove mysql. But there is another way to solve this that does not happen again?

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911096/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-mysql-web-version-6-8-3-0/29148048#29148048

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when deploying a website to the server (but not when debugging).

To fix it, select *References -> MySql.Data* and set the *Copy Local parameter* to *True*. When deployed on the server you can verify this by the presence of the `MySql.Data.dll` in the `bin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe if you remove or comment out the line with

```
<add name="MySQLRoleProvider"  />
```

see http://forums.asp.net/t/1928379.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears in general when you provide the DLL-File in the wrong CPU-Type. So maybe you supplied x86 but you need x64. But I'm not an expert in web-development. I know this error from developing .net-Services.

Answer (score 0):

secure_file_priv may be set as follows:

If empty, the variable has no effect.

If set to the name of a directory, the server limits import and export operations to work only with files in that directory. The directory must exist; the server will not create it.